# C# Looping through a CSV file/API call

Tags: c#, csv

I'm writing a console app that will look through three different folders (PathA, PathB, PathC) for csv files and email the customers inside. I need some help with the logic. For each email address in PathA, I want to call the api to send an email with TemplateA. For each email address in PathB, it needs TemplateB and so on. I'm not sure how I should be referencing each path and each template.

```
    static void RunTask(string[] args)
    {

       // List<DM.SendEmailRequest> response = GetEmailRequest();
        List<PathElement> paths = PathsConfig.GetCurrentPathConfiguration();
        foreach (PathElement folder in paths)//looks at every folder within main folder
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder.Path, "*.csv"))//looks at every file with the extension ".csv" in each folder
            {
                Debug.Write("\n" + file + "\n"); //writes out file names
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    String line;

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] parts = line.Split(',');

                        string email = parts[1];
                        Debug.Write(email + "\n");//writes out email column
                        foreach (var customer in email)
                        {
                            if (PathA){ //how do I actually reference this path?
                                //call API and send TemplateA
                        }
                            else if (PathB)
                            {
                                //call API and send TemplateB
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //call API and send TempateC
                            }
                    }


                    }
                }

            }
        }


    }


    private static List<DM.SendEmailRequest> GetEmailRequest()
    {
        using (var httpClient = GetHttpClient())
        {
            DM.SendEmailRequest request = new DM.SendEmailRequest();
            request.TemplateId = //A, B or C;
            request.RecipientAddress = //current recipient;


            var response = GetResponseString(httpClient, "SendEmail", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response) ? default(List<DM.SendEmailRequest>) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DM.SendEmailRequest>>(response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's a LOT of code. Have you narrowed down at all where the error might be occurring? I'd recommend [paring this down to as little code as possible while still reproducing the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you please show exactly what `PathsConfig.GetCurrentPathConfiguration()` returns?

Comment: what is your `List<PathElement> paths = PathsConfig.GetCurrentPathConfiguration();` populating with?

Comment: will they always be the same?  or could they be random?

Comment: Then in your If statement just do `if(folder == Paths[0]) {} elseif(folder ==paths[1]) {} else {}`

Comment: Alternativly,  if you wanted to be more direct (if you don't know what order they will be loaded into the list)  you could just go `if(folder.path.contains("first")) {}  elseif(folder.path.contains("second") {} else {}`   if path is not a string in your object,  then use `folder.path.ToString().contains("whatever")`

Comment: remove the foreach alltogehter,  your while loop is iterating through each line of the file.  your getting a single string value (email) out of each line  then telling it to do a "Foreach"  on a string.    you could implicitly declare the customer as a `string customer`  but then it would just force the foreach to only occur once,  EVERY time, which just adds compute power for 0 benifit/use (if it even workds,  i've never tried)

Comment: alternativly,  you could build a List<string> of emails from that file,  then inside your If's (which will now be outside the while loop) do a "Foreach" over the email list.

Comment: yup,  you still need the `line.split()`   have a look at the answer i posted below,  that should be what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is everything i would put inside the `Using` {}

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
    String line;
    List<string> myEmailList = new List<string>();

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(',');
        string email = parts[1];
        Debug.Write(email + "\n");//writes out email column
        myEmailList.Add(email);
    }
    foreach (var customer in myEmailList)
    {
        if (folder.path.Contains("first")){ 
             //Do stuff with "Customer"
             //call API and send TemplateA
        }    
        else if(folder.path.Contains("second"))
        {
             //Do stuff with "Customer"
             //call API and send TemplateB
        }
        else
        {
             //Do stuff with "Customer"
             //call API and send TempateC
        }
    }
}
```

Alternativly,  you can do it like below

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
    String line;

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(',');
        string email = parts[1];
        Debug.Write(email + "\n");//writes out email column
        if (folder.path.Contains("first")){
             //Do stuff with "email" 
             //call API and send TemplateA 
        }    
        else if(folder.path.Contains("second"))
        {
             //Do stuff with "email"
             //call API and send TemplateB
        }
        else
        {
             //Do stuff with "email"
            //call API and send TempateC
        }
    }
}
```

Option 1 will read through the entire file,  collect ALL email addresses in all CSV's in that folder and build a list of them,  then iterate through that list sending emails after it's finished reading all the files (i would recommend this one,  as it would allow you to get the full list, check for duplicates (if needed) etc before you send all the emails)

Option 2 will send an email to the customer in the current line before it proceeds to the next line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to do something like this:

```
static void RunTask(string[] args)
{
    var templates = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "C:\\test\\first", "A" },
        { "C:\\test\\second", "B" },
        { "C:\\test\\third", "C" },
    };

    List<PathElement> paths = PathsConfig.GetCurrentPathConfiguration();
    foreach (PathElement folder in paths)//looks at every folder within main folder
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder.Path, "*.csv"))//looks at every file with the extension ".csv" in each folder
        {
            Debug.Write("\n" + file + "\n"); //writes out file names
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                String line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] parts = line.Split(',');
                    string email = parts[1];
                    Debug.Write(email + "\n");//writes out email column
                    GetEmailRequest(templates[folder.Path], email);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

private static List<DM.SendEmailRequest> GetEmailRequest(string templateId, string recipientAddress)
{
    using (var httpClient = GetHttpClient())
    {
        DM.SendEmailRequest request = new DM.SendEmailRequest();
        request.TemplateId = templateId
        request.RecipientAddress = recipientAddress

        var response = GetResponseString(httpClient, "SendEmail", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response) ? default(List<DM.SendEmailRequest>) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DM.SendEmailRequest>>(response);
    }
}
```

I also think you could get your `RunTask` method down to this:

```
static void RunTask(string[] args)
{
    var templates = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "C:\\test\\first", "A" },
        { "C:\\test\\second", "B" },
        { "C:\\test\\third", "C" },
    };

    var responses =
    (
        from folder in PathsConfig.GetCurrentPathConfiguration()
        from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder.Path, "*.csv")
        from line in File.ReadLines(file)
        let email = line.Split(',')[1]
        select GetEmailRequest(templates[folder.Path], email)
    ).ToArray();
}
```